# How to close javafx and swing window threads between subsequent calls?

Tags: javafx, exit

Below is a functioning class that simulates extracting data from a website.  The question is how to close the window and threads after the data is retrieved?  The error message is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Platform.exit has been called
On line:  final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel() {
```

Here is the code.  When Platform.exit() is inserted at the indicated locations, the above error occurs.  In the actual code, javafx is used for obtaining and scanning the html text.  Also, javafx is used for setting attributes on the server and starting a program on the server, both done using java script.  The javafx functionality was removed from this minimal example that demonstrates the error that occurs when using Platform.exit().

```
public class Step11a {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException {
        Step11a st = new Step11a();
        st.getData();
        st.getData();
    }


    private JTable table;
    private String url;
    private WebView webView;
    public Step11a() {
        url = "https://www.tsp.gov/investmentfunds/shareprice/sharePriceHistory.shtml";
        table = new JTable();
    }
    private Scene createScene(ArrayBlockingQueue<DefaultTableModel> platfromQueue) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        Worker<Void> worker = webEngine.getLoadWorker();
        worker.stateProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
            if (worker.getState() == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                DefaultTableModel tableDataModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                // Following steps deleted for minimal example
                // 1) Get html code from server
                // 2) Locate elements to modify
                // 3) Create javascript string to modify element values
                // 4) Execute javascript to update elemetns
                // 5) Execute javascript to start data retrieval on server
                // 6) Get html and extract table of data
                // For this example, we just set the rows and columns 
                // in the table
                tableDataModel.setColumnCount(11);
                tableDataModel.setRowCount(24);;
                try {
                    platfromQueue.put(tableDataModel);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        webEngine.load(url);
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        return scene;
    }

    private DefaultTableModel initAndShowGUI() {    // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("WebViewTable");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 400);
            }
        };
        frame.add(fxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ArrayBlockingQueue<DefaultTableModel> platformQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<DefaultTableModel>(5) ;
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            initFX(fxPanel,platformQueue);
        });
        DefaultTableModel tspData = null;
        try {
            tspData = platformQueue.take();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Platform.exit();   // At this location causes error on next call
        // error occurs on final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel() {
        return tspData;
    }

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel, ArrayBlockingQueue<DefaultTableModel> platformQueue) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        //      System.out.println("JavaFx thread name "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Scene scene = createScene(platformQueue);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private DefaultTableModel getData() {
        ArrayBlockingQueue<DefaultTableModel> swingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(5);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DefaultTableModel tspDataLocal = initAndShowGUI( );
                    swingQueue.put(tspDataLocal);
                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        DefaultTableModel tableJFrameData = null;
        try {
            tableJFrameData = swingQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Platform.exit();   // At this location causes error on next call
        // error occurs on final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel() {

        return tableJFrameData;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is too much code, but if you want to shutdown the JavaFX Application thread, you can call [Platform.exit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--)

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes, I'll modify the code with a minimal example, and indicate where I've tried Platform.exit().

Comment: OK, I've added platform.exit in the two locations that make sense to me, but in both locations, it causes an error on the next iteration.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question?

Comment: OK, I made the example shorter, but it still includes passing data, since I don't know if that is part of the cause of the error when Platform.exit() is included.

Comment: Do you have to wrap JavaFX into Swing? If not, why not try extending Application - this seems to me more natural approach.

Comment: It's a stand alone class, called from an existing non-application program.  Can application extensions be called from external classes?  Or, maybe I shouldn't be using JavaFx.  All I need to do is modify a web site and parse some data.  I developed the code using webengine, but user interaction is not needed.  Is there a different way to download html then modify an input field, and download again, see original post / code for complete example.

Comment: IMO, JavaFX is an overkill for this. You can use libraries like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) which make things very easy.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into JSoup for revising attribute values / html processing.  That'll get rid of the threads and make everything a lot simpler.

Comment: Well, I took a quick look at JSoup.  I only see html processing capability.  I also need to execute JavaScript in order update the server attribute values and also to start the server script.

Comment: `Platform.exit()` will exit the JavaFX toolkit, so you will no longer be able to create any `JFXPanel`s, etc. You should only call `Platform.exit()` when you are going to exit the entire application.